# Dagger & Android - race conditions in tests?

Tags: android, android-testing, dagger

I am using Dagger to inject dependencies into activities in an Android project. All of the providers are kept in one module which is stored and managed by the `Application` subclass. Activities inject their dependencies in `onCreate()`, getting the module from the context.

In tests, I sometimes need to swap the default module for another one. I am using `ActivityAndroidTestCase2`. I get the application context before I call `getActivity()`, then substitute the module, like this:

```
Context applicationContext = getInstrumentation()
    .getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
module.setAppContext(applicationContext);
Thread.sleep(1000);         // note this
((ObjectGraphProvider) applicationContext).setModule(module);
```

The `MyApplication` code:

```
public class MyApp extends Application implements ObjectGraphProvider {

    private ObjectGraph objectGraph;
    private Object module;

    public MyApp() {
        super();
        ApplicationContextModule myModule = new DefaultModule();
        myModule.setAppContext(this);
        this.module = myModule;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(module);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectGraph objectGraph() {
        return objectGraph;
    }

    /* Test only */
    public void setModule(Object module) {
        this.module = module;
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(module);
    }
}
```

Sadly, the test fails from time to time - that's the reason for the `sleep()` in the first code snippet. The longer the thread sleeps, the smaller the chance of the failure, but it does not solve the problem for good.

Any ideas about what causes this strange behaviour and how to get over this issue?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it fails? Does it crash, do you get an error, is there anything useful in logcat?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered similar problems in my tests using Dagger and Cucumber-jvm. Here are a few gotchas to look out for:

- When you set your object graph to a new one, make sure there are no lingering references to components in the old graph. This means any Activities, Services, BroadcastReceivers, etc., that may still be active in the system and holding references to objects injected by your graph. Consider finishing all open activities before resetting the graph. In my case, I had a background service that was sticking around with injected references from the old graph. I had to explicitly call `stopSelf()` in the service to keep it from sticking around between test runs. This allowed it to get injections from the new graph when it started again.
- Use completely random IDs for PendingIntents, Notifications, and any other parts Android that take IDs. I was accidentally re-using IDs in my PendingIntents and this caused some tricky errors.
- Look for any other state that could persist before and after you reset the graph. I eventually came up with a procedure to completely clear my app state and start fresh: Clear all shared preferences, cancel all notifications, finish all opened activities, and then reset the graph.